Sufficient condition for a vector field to be an eigen vector field
Let $r_1,r_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth vector fields. What are the sufficient conditions on these vector fields so that there exists a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ whose eigen vector fields corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of the Jacobian matrix $Df$ are $r_1$ and $r_2$?
If such conditions exist, what is the analogue of this result in higher dimensions?

Socratic question: When does there exist an orthogonal matrix $R$ such that $R^\top JR=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2),?$

@KurtG. Iff J is symmetric matrix.  How does this help?

It helps to figure out how $J=Df$ has to look like so that the columns of $R$ are eigen vector fields of $Df,.$

If I understand correctly the answer I am looking for is the other way round. Given a Jacobian matrix, a vector field is its eigen field provided at every point it's parallel to the column vectors of the matrix P. But the question is how to characterize all the vector fields which are columns of P for some Jacobian matrix Df of some function f.


Let $R$ be the matrix whose columns are the vectors (fields) $r_1,r_2$ we start with and write $J=Df\,.$ Then $r_1,r_2$ are eigenvector fields of $Df$ iff $R$ is orthogonal and $R^\top JR=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\,.$ That is:
\begin{align}
Df&=R\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)R^\top\\[2mm]
&=\pmatrix{R_{11}^2\lambda_1+R_{12}^2\lambda_2&R_{11}R_{21}\lambda_1+R_{12}R_{22}\lambda_2\\R_{11}R_{21}\lambda_1+R_{12}R_{22}\lambda_2&R_{21}^2\lambda_1+R_{22}^2\lambda_2}\,.\tag1
\end{align}

Comparing $$Df=\pmatrix{\partial_1f_1&\partial_2f_1\\\partial_1f_2&\partial_2f_2}$$
with (1) we see that the function $f$ exists iff there exist functions $f_1,f_2$ such that
\begin{align}
\tag2\nabla f_1&=\pmatrix{R_{11}^2\lambda_1+R_{12}^2\lambda_2\,,&R_{11}R_{21}\lambda_1+R_{12}R_{22}\lambda_2}\,,\\[2mm]
\tag3\nabla f_2&=\pmatrix{R_{11}R_{21}\lambda_1+R_{12}R_{22}\lambda_2\,,&R_{21}^2\lambda_1+R_{22}^2\lambda_2}
\end{align}
hold.

Since $\mathbb R^2$ is simply connected this is the case iff the vector fields on the RHS of (2) and (3) are rotation free. That is: iff
\begin{align}
\tag4\partial_2\Big(R_{11}^2\lambda_1+R_{12}^2\lambda_2\Big)-\partial_1\Big(R_{11}R_{21}\lambda_1+R_{12}R_{22}\lambda_2\Big)&=0\,,\\[2mm]
\tag5\partial_2\Big(R_{11}R_{21}\lambda_1+R_{12}R_{22}\lambda_2\Big)-\partial_1\Big(R_{21}^2\lambda_1+R_{22}^2\lambda_2\Big)&=0
\end{align}
hold.



G Thanks for the answer. I have a doubt. Since the matrix Df need not be symmetric, we don't have orthogonality of the matrix R. Isn't it? R is only invertible.

The question was: what are the conditions on $R$ such that there exists an $f$ and so on. You should take my bullet points as hints and do some work to fill in the gaps.
